# Spring Security - Maximum sessions per user in runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

tried to find an answer here but couldn't find one which would fit my needs.

I'd like to allow the users set the maximum sessions per user from an UI. So, the application would start with an unlimited number of sessions but if the user wants, they can just change a setting and define a number of sessions per user.

Right now my code is like this.

```
            http
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(-1)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
```

So my questions is, how may I change maximumSessions per user from -1 to N number in runtime? Is it possible or I must restart the application?

spring-boot:2.6.7
spring-security-core:5.6.3

Thanks in advance.